Is that possible to include new fields in the change member tier quick action of a loyalty program member
I'm trying to figure it out how to include additional fields from the object Loyalty Member Tier while clicking in the standard quick action in the Loyalty Program Member record page.
I tried to edit the action but it doesn't show option to include additional fields.

Is there a way to include it by default?

